# Why is my single button LED light control only working sometimes?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I just started getting into Arduino and I put together a very simple led control with one button to change the on and off state. When I push the button the light will come on, but it will only stay on about 50% of the time (so I have to push it multiple times until it actually stays on), and The same thing happens when I try to turn it off.

Is there some problem with my code? Or is it likely to be a wiring issue?

```
 //define variables     

 int ledPin = 5;
 int btnOnPin = 9;
 bool isItOn = false;
 
 void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(btnOnPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  if(digitalRead(btnOnPin) == LOW)
  {
    if(isItOn == false)
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
      isItOn = true;
    }
    else if (isItOn == true)
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      isItOn = false;
    }
  }
}
```

The button is connected to ground and pin9, the led is connected to ground, and pin5 through a 220ohm resistor.

This should be super simple, but for some reason I can't get it to work properly.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Most likely your button is bouncing. Try and implement some debouncing, as shown here https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/Debounce

Comment: It is super simple. Learn about debouncing.

Answer (score 0):

try putting  the arduiton to sleep for a few milli seconds after changing its val

```
void loop() {
  if(digitalRead(btnOnPin) == LOW)
  {
    if(isItOn == false)
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
      isItOn = true;
    }
    else if (isItOn == true)
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      isItOn = false;
    }
    sleep(K);
  }
```